# My friend told me that he had a really long talk with his girlfriend yesterday at her home, which traumatized him - modifying scope

Tags: adjectives, relative-clauses

**Example 1**

> ‎"My friend told me that he had a really long talk with his girlfriend yesterday at her home, **which traumatized him and drained all of his energy.**"

Is this correct English?

My concern is that the scope of the sentence that "which" is modifying.

Is the word "which" modifying the whole sentence including "told"?

Comment: Common sense indicates that it was having the talk with the girlfriend which traumatised him. It could be argued that _which_ could refer to _her home_, but no-one would seriously interpret it that way.

Comment: The English is grammatical.  I would say that **which** scopes over the entire main clause, "My... at her home", and  that the sentence is ambiguous *structurally*. It is only  conventional expectation and common sense that lead the listener to understand it was the long talk with his girlfriend that traumatized him, not his telling you about it. One could keep the structure, but change the actors, the activity, and the location, and come to understand that it was the telling not the activity, that was traumatic.

Answer (score 0):

> My friend told me that he had [a really long talk with his girlfriend yesterday at her home], **which traumatized him and drained all of his energy**.

I add to what @Kate Bunting said.

The relative clause modifies the earlier noun phrase as bracketed.  It is unlikely to be interpreted as modifying *home* or *told me ... at her home*.

A different construction like the following may be interpreted as having its relative clause modify the entire preceding clause:

> After something happened, ... [my friend was interviewed by the police on the night's happenings after someone reported that he had a really long talk with his girlfriend yesterday at her home], **which traumatized him and drained all of his energy**.

We usually look at such details of a sentence to determine what its relative clause modifies.